# Jupyter Notebook : 'Bad config encountered during initialization. No such notebook dir : D:/ABC'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I run Windows10, use the latest Anaconda3 (2019) and have installed Jupyter Notebook through conda.

I used to run Jupyter Notebook by navigating to a folder where I save my Jupyter Notebooks named `\jupyter_notebook_files`  and from that directory running the command `jupyter notebook` from cmd.

A few hours ago I deleted for space saving reasons a folder named ABC.

When now I try to run Jupyter Notebook I get the message:

```
[C 20:57:04.610 NotebookApp] Bad config encountered during initialization:
[C 20:57:04.611 NotebookApp] No such notebook dir: ''D:/ABC''
```

I dealed with this problem by typing:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>jupyter notebook --notebook-dir='D:\DIGITAL_LIBRARY\Jupyter_Notebook_Files'
```

Is there a way to make this folder default and not have to repeat each time the clause: `-notebook-dir='D:\DIGITAL_LIBRARY\Jupyter_Notebook_Files'`  ?

Comment: There is no need to add `Your advice will be appreciated` to the footer of all of your questions. You've probably had ~100 removed by now.

Comment: Remember that the editors that try to keep this place tidy are volunteers. We may be foolish for taking on the task, but we believe in this community, for all its many faults. We would rather not have to clean up after users who add redundant and conversational material wilfully.

Answer (score 9):

Try to run this code on the terminal:

```
jupyter --config-dir
```

The output will be a path. Go to that folder and delete all the contents.

Then run

```
jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 4):

Close Anaconda and or any related programs that are running (Presumably Jupyter is not).  Drop down to the command prompt in Windows 10 (or other terminal if you have a different OS).  Enter the command:

```
jupyter --config-dir
```

This will give you the configuration directory for Jupyter, which will most likely look something like this:

> C:\Users<Your Local Account>.jupyter

use CD to go to that directory and use Notepad or your favorite text editor to edit the file called "jupyter_notebook_config.py" - for example:

```
notepad jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

Now use find (F3) to search for the line that begins with "c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = ".  The directory that follows the "=" sign probably doesn't exist. So copy that and create the directory OR enter the directory you want instead.

Save and Start Jupyter.